# sorting on searched records not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having problem in sorting the searched records in a gridview to ascending and descending directions. I have applied the following code to normal gridview (all records) and it is working all fine but when I try to search any records from all records, and try to sort those searched records, following code neither performs any actions nor throws any errors: Following code is applied for sorting:

```
protected void GridView2_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
{
    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    SortGridView1(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
}
else
{
    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    SortGridView1(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
}
}

private void SortGridView1(string sortExpression, string direction)
{

DataTable dt = SearchTable().Tables[0];

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

GridView2.DataSource = dv;
GridView2.DataBind();

 }
```

Search function code is:

```
public DataSet SearchTable()
{

    string sql1 = "SELECT * from dbo.Documents1";

    bool flag = false;

    if (!txtRef.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        if (flag == false)
        {
            sql1 = sql1 + " where Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
            flag = true;

        }
        else
        {
            sql1 = sql1 + "  and Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
        }
    }

    if (!txtSubject.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        if (flag == false)
        {
            sql1 = sql1 + " where Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
            flag = true;

        }
        else
        {
            sql1 = sql1 + "  and Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
        }
    }

    }

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = sql1 + ";";
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            //dataset object to get all select statement results
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //sql dataadoptor to fill dataset
            using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adp.Fill(ds);
            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return ds;

        }
    }
}
```

PageLoad Event function is:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = rpt.Documents1s.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();

            MultiView1.SetActiveView(vHome);

            btnBacktoHome.Visible = false;
            lblStatus.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

I cant understand where I am going wrong. when clicked on a column to sort, it took me out of searched records and sorted "All-Records" which are placed in GridView1 while searched-records are placed in GridView2 as shown in the code. what I am failed to understand is, why programs jumps to GridView1 and sort all-records there when I click to click to sort searched-records in GridView2. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the gridview binding code in inside of !ISPostBack ? like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //Grid Binding code 
    }
}
```

**Edit** for you page load code(Must add the databind in inside of !`IsPostBack`)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        GridView1.DataSource = rpt.Documents1s.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();

            BindGrid();

            MultiView1.SetActiveView(vHome);

            btnBacktoHome.Visible = false;
            lblStatus.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I need that to accomplish some other tasks.

Comment: Ramesh Rajendran , I have added Page_Load() for your review. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying. I applied your fix, and when clicked on a column to sort, it took me out of searched records and sorted "All-Records".